# how to find theme/template used by site created using Joomla

Tags: joomla, themes, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I would like to know the theme that is used by some website.

E.g. I would like to know the theme that is used by [this site](http://www.pizzahut.fr/) ([reference](http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/1271-pizza-hut.html)).

What are the steps to find the theme/template that is used by xyz site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speaking about Joomla specifically, it has a folder named templates in which templates are kept. I usually find out about the templates using

- The path (for joomla it would be /templates/(Theme Name)/style.css)
- By viewing source of the CSS files. A number of sites leave the template meta data untouched in there.

However, if the designer changes the template directory name or removes the meta data from within the css files or builds his/her own css from ground up. There wont be much left to identify the template. Hence you will have to do it the hard way , by identifying the CMS used and then browsing thru CMS specific templates. :)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: so what template is used for the site I provided?

Comment: The site used to be on joomla , you can see the site in the snapshot on Joomla's site is different from the one they have now. The current one uses Magento.  [link](http://www.pizzahut.fr/media/css/af9519c99cc4da7f643951c8479468d6.css) .  if you view this file there is a lot of meta data there . I would say the designer worked with the default theme of magento and modified the css.

Comment: its called pizza_new, which i believe is their own theme/template

Answer (score 3):

You can just open Firebug, inspect the page and it will some up with a few relevant links that will show you the template that is being used.

For example for the Pizza Hut website you provided:

*http://www.pizzahut.fr/skin/frontend/**pizza_new**/default/favicon.ico*

Answer (score 2):

**Joomla! 1.5.x sites**

```
<meta name="generator" content="Joomla! 1.5 - Open Source Content Management" />
```

**Joomla! 1.0.x sites**

```
<meta name="Generator" content="Joomla! - Copyright (C) 2005 - 2007 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved." />
```

**Type "/administrator" in the address bar after the URL.**

```
http://sitename/administrator   or http://sitename/index.php/administrator
```

**Type "?tp=1" after the url.You can view the template layout**

```
http://www.joomla.org/?tp=1
```

**You can view plugin/system/ or plugin/content/ in the source.**

```
http://sitename/plugins/system/plg_jausersetting/script.js
```

**css file path /templete/themename/style.css**

`http://sitename/templates/colette/css/template.css`